# Passing an extra param when submitting form generated with form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, get, parameters, form-helpers

I have a form:

```
<%= form_tag(example_path, method: :get) do %>
…
<% end %>
```

I would like like to pass an extra parameter along with the form params:

```
example: 1
```

I've tried passing a hash into the path helper, but the params are ignored:

```
form_tag(example_path(example: 1), method: :get)
```

How can I add this param **without using a hidden field**.

Comment: That's odd, if I take off the `method: :get` it passes the extra param with the form's values, but if I add `method: :get`, it ignores them. Probably because the form is serialized and passed as get params, replacing the ones defined "manualy"  -- A workaround is to use post and get params: `form_tag(example_path(example: 1))`: params[:example] is a GET param whereas all the params in the form will be POST

Comment: @MrYoshiji Unfortunately it's a search form and I want the params in the URL.

Comment: I understand, maybe you could use Javascript to add it manually, but the best to add extra GET params is still the hidden field.

Answer (score 1):

In order to what you want to accomplish, you need to update your route:

```
# config/routes.rb

get "example/:your_param" => "your_controller#example", :as => :example
```

And then, you will be able to do this in your view:

```
<%= form_tag (example_path('value'), method: :get) do %>
....
```

I hope this makes sense and help you.